# How to optimze the query (which tooks to long)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query which I want to know relatively how many locations are up to 100 meters away (relate to all distances):

```
select person_tbl.tdm, sum((st_distance (person_tbl.geo, location_tbl.geo) < 100)::INT)::FLOAT / count(*)
from persons as person_tbl, locations as location_tbl
where person_tbl.geo is not null
group by person_tbl.tdm
```

The 2 tables contains geometry indexs:

```
create index idx on persons using gist(geo)
create index idx on locations using gist(geo)
```

The first table (`persons`) the values of `geo` field is `POLYGON`

The second table (`locations`) the values of `geo` field are `POINT Z` or `POLYGON Z` or `MULTIPOLYGON Z`

The first table `persons` contains ~2M rows and the second table `locations` contains ~500 rows

The query took too long (~2 hours).

The values of `max_parallel_processes` and `max_parallel_workers` is 8

- Is there something I can do to optimize the query calculation time (2 hours seems too long) ?
- Is there a better way to write the query ? or do I need to define the indexes in other way ?

Comment: You are not joining your two tables so you create a cartesian/cross product between the two. You should join them somehow: `from persons p join locations l on p.??? = l.????`

Comment: why the index is not beeing used ? and why the index will be used when we are using join command ?